# Splitting Changesets?

Tags: tfs

We have TFS2010 in our .NET shop and I have a changeset checked in that has several files in it. For organizational reasons I need to split that changeset into smaller ones. Is there an easy way of doing this other than rolling back the changes and recommitting them to TFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sadly the only way to do it is to perform a rollback.

If you have independent changes in each file, by that I mean that a change in A.cs is not relied upon by B.cs, then you can go through the pending changes just checking the files you need for each new changeset.

It is best practice to make each changeset (in any VCS) [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_commit#Revision_Control), this not only avoids the problem you have encountered, but also allows changesets to rollbacked in the event they need to be removed (i.e. they introduce a bug that you don't have time to fix before a release).